# Is this opps desing is good ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Asp.Net MVC-5 project, using code-first approach for database design. I have a question about my code design.

I have an Entity in my database schema name **Student**:

```
public partial class Student
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string RollNumber { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Mobile { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that i have declared this as partial because i extend it and include all the function process on student. Like this:

```
public partial class Student
{
   [NotMapped]
   private MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

   public static Student Get(int id)
   {
     Student student;
     using(MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
     {
       student = context.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id)
     }
     return student;
   }

   public void Student Create()
   {
     context.Students.Add(this);
     context.SaveChanges();
   }

   ....
   and similarly many other
}
```

Notice that i have declared a *static Get function* which takes id and return Student object it exist otherwise null. I have declared this static because it already returning an Student object so calling it with object seems unreasonable to me (please correct me if i am wrong).

Second thing to notice is *NotMapped* attribute which i used to exclude this property from mapping to database when running migrations.

So i am using the above mentioned design with my all entities (i.e. Wrapping data and function processing over that data into a single object). I want to know is this design approach is good OR is there any other better approach exist OR i am on a wrong path ??

Comment: This would be a better fit on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no such thing as correct or wrong design. Nevertheless, **you have already recognized the need to keep the entities and the retrieval access distinct**, by using two different files of the same partial class. I would keep them totally separated in different modules.

I would strongly suggest using the [**repository** pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) you could find a guide on how to implement it and combine it with the [**unit of work**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) pattern.

In the short version, a **repository** is a class handling the **data access operations for a specific entity type**.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `NotMapped` attribute because the context is a private field, not a property. As for using the methods on the class for Get, Create, etc., that is known as the Active Record pattern and its just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

you should try **[ASP.NET Scaffolding](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview)**